# FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - Not able to create main.jsbundle

Tags: ios, react-native, aws-sdk, react-native-ios, visual-studio-app-center

I do have a problem with my react-native mobile app. We are using

- "aws-iot-device-sdk": "^2.2.4", "aws-sdk": "^2.678.0",

in our app for our mqtt services.The app is working in the debug mode in ios but when configured for the app-center , it failed and the following error was shown saying about the javascript heap out of memory.

> ````
> transform[stdout]: ==== JS stack trace
> ========================================= transform[stdout]:  transform[stdout]:     0: ExitFrame [pc: 0xd2c3765be3d]
> transform[stdout]: Security context: 0x2a26ce71e6e9 <JSObject>
> transform[stdout]:     1: /* anonymous */ [0x2a26d406ba61]
> [/Users/XXX/Work/XXX/XXX/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:~77]
> [pc=0xd2c379b8dbc](this=0x2a26d40456e1 <JSFunction traverse (sfi =
> 0x2a2688adac91)>,node=0x2a2621d1d6c1 <Node map =
> 0x2a26e47c9639>,opts=0x2a261b943559 <Object map =
> 0x2a26e47831d1>,scope=0x2a26423b0f01 <Scope map =
> 0x2a26e4784569>,sta... transform[stdout]:  transform[stderr]: FATAL
> ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed -
> JavaScript heap out of memory transform[stderr]:  1: 0x10003cf99
> node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node] transform[stderr]:  2: 0x10003d1a3
> node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
> transform[stderr]:  3: 0x1001b7835
> v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char
> const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node] transform[stderr]:  4: 0x100585682
> v8::internal::Heap::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*)
> [/usr/local/bin/node] transform[stderr]:  5: 0x100588155
> v8::internal::Heap::CheckIneffectiveMarkCompact(unsigned long, double)
> [/usr/local/bin/node] transform[stderr]:  6: 0x100583fff
> v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector,
> v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node] transform[stderr]:  7:
> 0x1005821d4
> v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace,
> v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags)
> [/usr/local/bin/node] transform[stderr]:  8: 0x10058ea6c
> v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLigthRetry(int,
> v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment)
> [/usr/local/bin/node] transform[stderr]:  9: 0x10058eaef
> v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int,
> v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment)
> [/usr/local/bin/node] transform[stderr]: 10: 0x10055e434
> v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool,
> v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [/usr/local/bin/node]
> transform[stderr]: 11: 0x1007e6714
> v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInNewSpace(int, v8::internal::Object**,
> v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node] transform[stderr]: 12:
> 0xd2c3765be3d  transform[stdout]:  transform[stdout]: <--- Last few
> GCs ---> transform[stdout]:  transform[stdout]: [23942:0x102b00000]  
> 374196 ms: Scavenge 1374.0 (1423.8) -> 1373.7 (1424.3) MB, 11.0 / 0.0
> ms  (average mu = 0.109, current mu = 0.018) allocation failure 
> transform[stdout]: [23942:0x102b00000]   402358 ms: Mark-sweep 1374.4
> (1424.3) -> 1374.1 (1423.8) MB, 28158.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.062,
> current mu = 0.009) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
> transform[stdout]: [23942:0x102b00000]   402424 ms: Scavenge 1374.8
> (1423.8) -> 1374.5 (1424.3) MB, 29.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.062,
> current mu = 0.009) allocation failure```
> ````

I could see many articles saying about adding :

```
shellScript = "export NODE_BINARY=\"'node --max_old_space_size=8192'\n../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh\"\n";
```

in the **project.pbxproj** file inside the

> /* Bundle React Native Code And Images */

section. This was added and app-center build was successful but the application crashed using when installed ipa in real device.

I tried to get create the ipa using the Archive option in Xcode and xcode failed throwing the main.jsbundle could not be found.
Tried creating the **main.jsbundle** using the command

```
react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false
--bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

but this also failed showing the heap exception which is the same as I got in app-center.
At the same time debug mode is working fine though I had the same heap problem, I started the bundler using the

```
"node --max-old-space-size=8192
 node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
```

Not sure how to create a release build for iOS. It would be really helpful if someone can help me to identify a fix for this.
Did anyone face this problem and able to resolve this ?

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5350U CPU @ 1.80GHz
    Memory: 685.68 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 10.16.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.15.2 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: Not Found
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 23, 27, 28, 29
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.6 AI-192.7142.36.36.6392135
    Xcode: 11.3.1/11C504 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Python: 2.7.17 - /usr/local/bin/python
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 16.11.0 => 16.11.0 
    react-native: 0.62.0 => 0.62.0 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```